# Finding relative position in honeycomb structure

Tags: geometry

[image]

Hi. I have a bit technical question related to geometry. Let's assume that we have a two-dimensional honeycomb structure with a set of regular hexagon with a side length of $l$, as shown above with the periodic boundary condition. For any point $(x,y)$ in such plane, it would be inside one of the hexagon in honeycomb structure. (In here, I ignore the case in which the point is on the boundary of hexagon.) I want to find the formula which suggest the "relative position" of $(x,y)$, where the origin of the belonged hexagon is shifted to $(0,0)$.

For the algorithm, this is very straightforward. First, we have to find the 'nearest' center position $(a,b)$ of the hexagon for the point $(x,y)$. Then, the relative position of the point $(x,y)$ would be $(x',y')=(x-a,y-b)$. The thing is that I have to write the function $f(x,y)$ that convert $x,y$ into $x'$ and $y'$. Then, it is not possible to convert the process of finding the nearest center position into the formula. **One restriction is that the expression is only able to be involved with the function sin, cos, sec, csc, tan, cot, asin, acos, atan, sinh, cosh, tanh, erf, erfc, min, max, abs, floor, ceil, step, delta.**

I think there should be an analytic expression that converts $(x,y)$ into $(x',y')$. For the cubic case, we can use the formula $f(x)=cos^{-1}(cos(x))$ to limit the range of x in the interval [-1,1]. I think this kind of the trick could be used in the expression to find the relative position, but I have not much idea about solving this problem. Any advice or answer would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: First you need to define how your hexagonal grid is positioned in the coordinate system. If you do that, you should be able to get formula for centers of the hexagons fairly easy as all of them will be equally distanced on a bunch of equally distanced parallel lines.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use standard arithmetic operations like +, -, *, / ?

Comment: @JohnHughes Standard arithmetic operations are also allowed

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3058657/converting-a-point-to-a-hexagon-coordinate/3059458#3059458) to an earlier question may be helpful.

Comment: @DanielMathias That answer is indeed very helpful for me! I think it's very straightforward to get the relative position since such answer gives the formula to write the center of nearest hexagon. Thanks for your incredible work.

Comment: If my answer there resolves your question, we can mark this one as a duplicate.